# Firebase google library using weak SHA 1 hash algorithm while scanning through MobSF security tool

Tags: android, firebase

We are using below Google libraries in our android App like

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.0.1
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.1
```

We are getting your app is using  "SHA-1" weak hash algorithm while scanning through MobSF security tool. How to fix this?

Comment: did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

what is the exact source file which contains the SHA1 hash?
something like that
[image]

Then, after checking the code, I can see the comment
[image]

That means even if Firebase uses SHA1 hash, it should not be a security issue